# What is the best way to speedup GCC?

Tags: gcc

Every time I compile my code in GCC it takes about a minute.  What is the best way to speed this up?  Should I just buy a newer faster computer?

Comment: Speeding up the bottlenecks on your machine (presumably CPU and memory for a compiler unless it's caching everything to disk) will reduce your compile-time, yes.

Comment: Can you provide more information on how you are invoking it? What options?

Comment: Currently I am working on a plugin for the "R" language which makes calls to C.  The C code is compiled when inside the "R" interpreter I type 'install.packages("package.tar.gz", repos=NULL)'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to speed up recompiles of a developing code is to cache the compiler outputs with [ccache](http://ccache.samba.org/). It will work best if only small parts of the code get modified.

Additionally, if you have access to a lot of machines [distcc](http://distcc.samba.org/) allows you to distribute your compile jobs over a network (that way I can say without fear "Do me a `make -j100`!). Depending on how many machines you have available this might give a sizeable speed boost.

Comment: Any idea how to use ccache for installing an R p

Comment: `install.packages` just calls the compiler, and ccache mimics the compiler for all practical purposes, so you shouldn't need to do anything special for your R use case.